# CodeIgniter | .htaccess removing index.php from url Mac os yosemite

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, osx-yosemite

I'm having problem removing `index.php` from url.. I've tried a lot of google tips and no success. I'm using mac os x yosemite, php 5.5.0 and Apache 2.4.10. Please, does any one nows what happenning?

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] ='http://localhost/~veniciobr/iTicket';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: in  application/config/config.php do you have $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI'; ? check https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the rewrite base :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /~veniciobr/iTicket/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Restart Apache and check also if your mod_rewrite extension is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /iTicket/index.php?/$1 [L]
```